# CSS: Why are descendant elements removed from parent block?

Tags: css

In my code below, the bottom border of the "question-content" div does not appear at the bottom; it actually cuts through the "li" elements. Analyzing this in Firebug shows that the li class="tag" descendant elements are no longer included in the "question-content" parent block.

How should I fix this? Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
    .question-block {
        margin: 10px 10px 0;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .question-block .question-content {
        margin: 0 0 10px 55px;
        padding: 0 0 20px 0;
        width: 545px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    }
    .question-content h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 22px;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0px;
    }
    .question-content .question-details {
        margin-left: 30px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .question-content .links {
        margin-left: 30px;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .tag {
float: left;
margin: 5px 4px 0;
font-size: 14px;
    }
    .tag a {
    display: block;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px;
border-radius: 4px;
height: 20px;
color: #000;
background: #C5C5C5;
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
width: 81px;
text-align: center;
    }
   </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="question-block">      
        <div class="question-content">
            <h1> Question </h1>
            <div class="question-details"> Question details </div>
            <ul class="links">
                 <li class="tag"><a href="#">tag 1</a></li>
                 <li class="tag"><a href="#">tag 2</a></li>
                 <li class="tag"><a href="#">tag 3</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually solve this problem by declaring child element (`ul.links` in your case) with `display:inline-block` attribute. It'll prevent child from crossing borders of parent container.

http://jsfiddle.net/9sQXk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow: auto` to .question-content

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `<li>` list items are floating.

Try adding a block level element with a `clear:both` style after the closing `</ul>`.

So:

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
    .question-block {
        margin: 10px 10px 0;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .question-block .question-content {
        margin: 0 0 10px 55px;
        padding: 0 0 20px 0;
        width: 545px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    }
    .question-content h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 22px;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0px;
    }
    .question-content .question-details {
        margin-left: 30px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .question-content .links {
        margin-left: 30px;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .tag {
float: left;
margin: 5px 4px 0;
font-size: 14px;
    }
    .tag a {
    display: block;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px;
border-radius: 4px;
height: 20px;
color: #000;
background: #C5C5C5;
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
width: 81px;
text-align: center;
    }
.clearfloat {
clear: both;
}
   </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="question-block">      
        <div class="question-content">
            <h1> Question </h1>
            <div class="question-details"> Question details </div>
            <ul class="links">
                 <li class="tag"><a href="#">tag 1</a></li>
                 <li class="tag"><a href="#">tag 2</a></li>
                 <li class="tag"><a href="#">tag 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfloat"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've specified that anything with the class "`tag`" will have "`float: left`".

Float removes an element from the regular flow layout of a document.  In other words, the containing `<ul>` and `<div>` blocks are no longer adjusted for the height of the `<li>`'s that are inside the list.

You need to remove the float if you want your list items to appear inside their containers, rather than float to the left of the rest of the document.  Alternately, you can float the entire thing, by putting the float property on the containing div.